# Spring boot, possible causes of View cannot be resolved issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

What could be the problem if Spring Boot cannot resolve view with specific name?

I have developed many Spring Boot applications before and have never encountered this problem.

I have following folder structure:

```
/src/main/java
/src/main/resources/config
/src/main/resources/static
/src/main/resources/static/partials
/src/main/resources/static/resources
```

Image:

[image]

`/src/main/resources/static/resources` folder is not making problems for having `resources` name. I tried renaming it and it didn't solve problem.

I am using Maven and I have parent project which has multiple children projects.

Module for the rest api contains many configuration classes, including configurations for security.

Everything is working as it should, application can be started without errors, but when I tried to add static content I encountered this problem.

From the following example ([example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static)) we can see that Spring Boot should automatically maps `src/main/resources/static/index.html` to the root path, but that is not happening in my application. From the log I can see that Spring didn't find mapping for `/`.

I am able to run that example normally, but in my application it is not working.
Because Spring didn't map automatically I created `WelcomeController` which should return view:

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeRestController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

After I did that, mapping is found, but Spring reports that it couldn't resolve view with name `index.html` even if it exists.

I tried adding static content to `src/main/webapp/static` folder even if it is not recommended and it also didn't work, same problem, cannot resolve view.

I also tried to configure using

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) { 
         registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
     }

 }
```

Again, view cannot be resolved.

My application's start point:

```
@Import(MyRestServiceConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {

        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

I am using embedded Tomcat.

Is it possible that security configurations or some other configurations except `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` are having influence on views?

I am trying to resolve this issue for hours but I can't find soulution. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I am not building application using Maven, just running `Application.java` as Java Application, so Maven should not be a problem.

EDIT:
Content of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head lang="en">

    </head>
    <body>

        <div>Hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle In Maven menu I have only Add Dependency, Add Plugin etc..

Comment: Anything in `static` is for direct consumption without handler/view processing. If you have a handler method (e.g. `welcome()`) that returns a view name, then a view resolver must process that, and not from the `static`. What view technologies are you going to use? Thymeleaf? Freemarker? JSP? E.g. Thymeleaf will by default read view files from the `template` folder, not the `static` folder.

Comment: @Andreas It's just simple html. I edited my question to include index.html content.

Comment: If there's no dynamic content, why do you have a handler method? Remove the handler method, and the static content should work.

Comment: I was just trying different configurations to make it work. That was not a problem. The problem was in the @EnableWebMvc annotation in MyRestServiceConfiguration. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, but I am not really sure why this makes problem. Please post your answer if you know why is this happening.

The problem was `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in `MyRestServiceConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
// @EnableWebMvc
@Import(MyServiceConfiguration.class)
    public class MyRestServiceConfiguration {

}
```

After removing it, everything works as it should.

From Spring Boot guide:

*Normally you would add @EnableWebMvc for a Spring MVC app, but Spring Boot adds it automatically when it sees spring-webmvc on the classpath. This flags the application as a web application and activates key behaviors such as setting up a DispatcherServlet.*

It's clear that `@EnableWebMvc` annotation is not needed, but why does it make problems?

EDIT:

From Spring Boot reference:

*The easiest way to take complete control over MVC configuration is to provide your own @Configuration with the @EnableWebMvc annotation. This will leave all MVC configuration in your hands.*

From Spring's `@EnableWebMvc` documentation:

*Adding this annotation to an @Configuration class imports the Spring MVC configuration from WebMvcConfigurationSupport, e.g.:*

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebMvc
 @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { MyConfiguration.class })
 public class MyWebConfiguration {

 }
```

So, the problem was that `@EnableWebMvc` annotation dissabled default Spring Boot's configuration and because of that Spring didn't know where to look for static resources. If I got something wrong, please correct me.